# Using atomic bool as a flag with non-atomic interface

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'd like to use `atomic<bool>` for thread synchronization, but, in this case, I can't use it with third-party library that accepts only `volatile bool` - here's the example:

```
void ThirdPartyFunction(const volatile bool *isRunning) {
   while(*isRunning) {
      // do some work
   }
   return;
}
```

My code would use it like this:

```
volatile bool isFunctionRunning {false};

void ThreadFunction() {
   ThirdPartyFunction(&isFunctionRunning);
}

void StartFunction() {
   isFunctionRunning = true;
}

void StopFunction() {
   isFunctionRunning = false;
}

int main() {
   StartFunction();
   std::thread t{ThreadFunction};
   // some work
   StopFunction();
   t.join();

   // ...
}
```

My intention is to make `isFunctionRunning` atomic, but I don't know the way to pass it to third-party function. Is using `volatile` enough if I don't care about memory reordering (if it doesn't matter if the thread would end immediately or run a loop one more time)? If not, is there a way to use `atomic`, or should I use `mutex`?

Comment: Perhaps use `std::atomic_thread_fence`? See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence

For this scenario (a stop flag) it's probably not particularly critical.

Comment: A `volatile bool` is uncool, but if the library insists on using one, nothing bad should happen if use it.

Comment: Simply type cast, i.e. ThirdPartyFunction( const_cast<volatile bool*>( &atomic.load() ) ); and use your C function. std::atomic is a wrapper class around the volatile variable, other words you have a guaranty that variable not optimized and RAM memory allocated, and not just registers in use. In any case you can make a wrapper class on top of 3D party C API instead, and use regular class member instead of std::atomic wrapper

Comment: @VictorGubin `&atomic.load()` won't compile. `load()` returns an rvalue.